# sort an array that contains NSRange values

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is an array with some NSRange values:

`@[[NSVale valueWithRange:{5,3}],[NSVale valueWithRange:{2,3}],[NSVale valueWithRange:{7,3}],[NSVale valueWithRange:{1,3}],....]`

every `range` has a different `location`, I want the array to be sorted by `range.location` in inverse order,any good solution?

Comment: I've improved my answer, please see updated code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[sortedArrayUsingComparator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) is the best choice for your task.

Code for your case is:

```
NSArray *array = @[[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(5,3)],
                   [NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,3)],
                   [NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(7,3)],
                   [NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,3)]];

array = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSValue *value1, NSValue *value2) {
        NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedSame;
        if (value1.rangeValue.location > value2.rangeValue.location) {
            result = NSOrderedAscending;
        } else if (value1.rangeValue.location < value2.rangeValue.location) {
            result = NSOrderedDescending;
        }
        return result;
}];
```

Comment: Your comparator block is wrong. It should return NSOrderedSame if the objects are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Visput shows how to order the array with a comparator in reversed order. While that code works it has one downside: he reverses the order by returning `NSOrderedDescending` for x < y,  and `NSOrderedAscending` for x > y but this is actually confusing as this is the opposite of what math and nature tells us. If you just sort once that might be ok, but if you re-use the comparator it might be confusing, especially if you want to be able to switch ascending and descending.

So I would propose to keep the natural ordering of the relations `<` and `>` and reverse the sorted array. arrays can be reversed easily with `[[array reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects]`

Here with a comparator block for both orders.

```
NSArray *array = @[[NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(5,3)],
                   [NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,3)],
                   [NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(7,3)],
                   [NSValue valueWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,3)]];

NSComparator compr = ^NSComparisonResult(NSValue *value1, NSValue *value2) {
    NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedSame;
    if (value1.rangeValue.location < value2.rangeValue.location) {
        result = NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (value1.rangeValue.location > value2.rangeValue.location) {
        result = NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return result;
};


NSArray *descArray = [[[array sortedArrayUsingComparator:compr] reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
NSArray *ascArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:compr];

NSLog(@"descending\n%@\n\nascending\n%@", descArray, ascArray);;
```

result:

```
descending
(
    "NSRange: {7, 3}",
    "NSRange: {5, 3}",
    "NSRange: {2, 3}",
    "NSRange: {1, 3}"
)

ascending
(
    "NSRange: {1, 3}",
    "NSRange: {2, 3}",
    "NSRange: {5, 3}",
    "NSRange: {7, 3}"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr]`. The comparator is a block that will take 2 objects (NSValues if you use your array). The result of the comparator defines the order of the output array.

Answer (score 0):

A sure fire way to sort any array no matter what the type is to use NSArray's method `sortedArrayUsingComparator` (documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator:). Essentially, you will pass in a block that returns `NSOrderedAscending` if the second value has a higher location, and vice versa for descending.

Hope this helps!